# Two list Fragments dependent each other on a single Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an Activity that contains four Fragments. Three of them are dependent lists. Dependent means that values shown in third one are related to selected item of second one and values shown in second one are related to the selected item of first list.

If I add fragments in layout, I have no way to initialize them with selected item of another fragment. So I decided to create them inside Activity's onCreate method as below:

```
...
if (isLargeLayout) {
    list1Fragment = List1Fragment.newInstance();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(list1).commit(); // Simplified Code

    list2Fragment = List2Fragment.newInstance(list1Fragment.getSelectedItem()); // <--
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(list2).commit();

    // ...
 }
```

When I want to add second fragment, `list1Fragment` is not attached yet so listView inside it is null.
Now my question is when really a fragment attaches to Activity and starts its lifecycle? And how can I have a fragment created by data from another activity?

Comment: You want to send the related values to nextfragment from current fragment ??

Comment: yes, as I told these three fragments related on each other.

Comment: Use   Bundle and pass data in between these fragment. If you want i will explain you how to send and retrieve data using bundle in between fragment ..